# removing a duplicated item from a python list

Tags: python, list, del

I'm tring to remove the maximum value from a list that has a repeated maximum value for example: [1,3,6,6,5]
the code i use only removes one of the values wihtout removing the other. any ideas why is that happening?  the code i use is:

```
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())
    lst = list (arr)
    for i in lst:
        if i == max(lst):
            del(lst[lst.index(i)])
    print (max(lst))
```

Comment: It's almost always better to make a new list with the ones you WANT to keep.  One line:   `newlst = [i for i in lst if i != max(lst)]`.

Comment: Changing a list while you iterate through it is problematic.  If the input was [3,2,1] would you want to delete all elements?

Comment: What is the expected behavior if the max value in the list is present more than two times?

Answer (score 1):

This code is the problem:

```
for i in lst:
    if i == max(lst):
        del(lst[lst.index(i)])
```

As @AllanWind commented, when you call `del` to remove the item from the list, this changes the *size* of the list, which causes the outer `for i in lst` loop to get out of sync with the actual list contents.

Don't add/remove items to a list as you're iterating over it.

For this specific use case, this code would be a lot better:

```
m = max(lst)
while m in lst:
    lst.remove(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter (and if you wish assign the result to the same `lst`):

```
lst = [1, 3, 6, 6, 5]
lst2 = list(filter(lambda f: f != max(lst), lst))
```